# Creating AWS initialization class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-2.0

I have a API which connects to my dynamo db. My API has quite a few endpoints for GET, POST, Delete etc. I am using the following code:

```
var awsCredentials = Helper.AwsCredentials(id, password);
var awsdbClient = Helper.DbClient(awsCredentials, "us-east-2");
var awsContext = Helper.DynamoDbContext(awsdbClient);

List<ScanCondition> conditions = new List<ScanCondition>();
var response = await context.ScanAsync<MyData>(conditions).GetRemainingAsync();

return response.ToList();
```

The first three lines of my code ie setting awsCredentials, awsdbClient & awsContext are repeated in each of my WEB API call.

And this is my static helper class:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static BasicAWSCredentials AwsCredentials(string id, string password)
    {
        var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(id, password);
        return credentials;
    }
    public static AmazonDynamoDBClient DynamoDbClient(BasicAWSCredentials credentials, RegionEndpoint region)
    {
        var client = new DBClient(credentials, region);
        return client;
    }
    public static DynamoDBContext DynamoDbContext(AmazonDynamoDBClient client)
    {
        var context = new DynamoDBContext(client);
        return context;
    }
}
```

I use this helper class in my API to initialize AWS.

Is there a better way to initialize this?

Comment: Is this Asp.Net, or are you able to use Dependency Injection? If not, could you make your `awsdbClient` or `awsContext` static so you only need to create those once when the application boots?

Comment: This is asp.net core

Comment: How can I use dependency injection here and add that in my start up class

Comment: aws provides a bunch of interfaces for everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take advantage of ASP.Net's built-in Dependency Injection.

We need to make a quick interface to expose the values you need.

```
public interface IDynamoDbClientAccessor
{
    DynamoDBContext GetContext();
}
```

And a settings class that we'll use in a bit.

```
public class DynamoDbClientAccessorSettings
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
}
```

Now the concrete class.

```
public class DynamoDbClientAccessor : IDynamoDbClientAccessor
{
    private readonly DynamoDbClientAccessorSettings settings;

    public DynamoDbClientAccessor(IOptions<DynamoDbClientAccessorSettings> options)
    {
        settings = options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
    }

    public DynamoDBContext GetContext()
    {
        // You have the option to alter this if you don't
        // want to create a new context each time. 
        // Have a private variable at the top of this class
        // of type DynamoDBContext. If that variable is not null,
        // return the value. If it is null, create a new value,
        // set the variable, and return it.

        var awsCredentials = Helper.AwsCredentials(settings.Id, settings.Password);
        var awsdbClient = Helper.DbClient(awsCredentials, settings.Region);
        var awsContext = Helper.DynamoDbContext(awsdbClient);

        return awsContext;
    }
}
```

Hook all of this up in your Startup class

```
services.AddSingleton<IDynamoDbClientAccessor, DynamoDbClientAccessor>();
services.Configure<DynamoDbClientAccessorSettings>(c =>
{
    c.Id = "YOUR ID";
    c.Password = "YOUR PASSWORD";
    c.Region = "YOUR REGION";
});
```

Now in your controller or other DI service you ask for a `IDynamoDbClientAccessor` instance in the constructor.

Once you get more familar with Dependency Injection you'll be able to break apart more things into their own dependent services. As [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733932/creating-aws-initialization-class#comment90428881_51733932) says, the AWS SDK even provides some interfaces for you to use which can help as well.

Comment: Thanks @gunr2171 for the detailed explanation, this really helped me. I actually found AWS documentation to be less detailed. May be I need to dig more into that.